# Mutagen Key Error

Tags: python, keyerror, mutagen

the code below is a code to try and get the tags off of a mp3 file using mutagen and then automatically update the tags which are non-existent using the mutagen api. The problem comes when we try and update the tags which are not there. Any Help would be appreciated. I am not proficent in the python language as i only started coding 6 months ago.

```
#import mutagen
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

def readid3mp3(ip):

    audio = MP3(ip)

    if ((audio['TPE1']) == 0):
         tags.add = ID3()
         tags.add(TPE1(encoding=3, text =["Not Available"]))

    else:
         Art = (audio['TPE1'])

    if ((audio['TIT2']) == 0):
        tags.add =ID3()
        tags.add(TIT2(encoding=3, text ="Not Available"))

    else:
         Song = (audio['TIT2'])


    if ((audio['TALB']) is None):
         tags.add = ID3()
         tags.add(TALB(encoding=3, text ="Not Available"))

    audio = MP3(ip)    

    Art  = (audio['TPE1'])
    Song = (audio['TIT2'])
    Alb  = (audio['TALB'])

    print(audio['TIT2'])
    print(audio['TPE1'])
    print(audio['TALB'])


#Print into file

    myFile.write ("\n"+"Artist"+"\t \t \t Song Name" + "\t Album Name" )
    myFile.write ("\n"+ str(Art) + "\t" + str(Song) + "\t" + str(Alb))

#Close File
myFile.close()

return


#Open File
myFile = open("AlbArtSong.txt", "a+")

#Enter Inputs

ip = input("Enter Mp3 file: ")

readid3mp3(ip)
```

The "Not Available" is temporary until i sort out the api

and this is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\patri_000\Desktop\Uni Stuff\EE106\Progect\test.py", line     59, in <module>
    readid3mp3(ip)
  File "C:\Users\patri_000\Desktop\Uni Stuff\EE106\Progect\test.py", line 23, in readid3mp3
    if ((audio['TALB']) is None):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_file.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self.tags[key]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    return self.__dict[key]
KeyError: 'TALB'
```

I know what the error means i just don't know how to get around it or fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutagen objects that support subscription like that act just like [Python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). Use a membership test to see if the key is there, or use the [`.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) to return a default if the entry is missing:

```
if 'TALB' in audio:
    Alb  = audio['TALB']
```

or

```
Alb  = audio.get('TALB')  # returns None as a default
```

or

```
Alb  = audio.get('TALB', 'No album title')  # alternative default
```